# why does JavaFX automatically resize images?

Tags: java, javafx-11

I have a 200x200 image.

[image]

I load the above image into an ImageView but when I run the JavaFX application, the image appears larger.  I took a screen capture and opened it in Paint.NET to confirm.

[image]

Why is the image now 348x348?  I tried everything I could think of to restrain the width and height to 200x200 (sample code below).  This [Images automatically resized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48351124/images-automatically-resized) post is the closest thing I could find relating to my question but I am not developing for Android.

```
public class ImageTest extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Pane pane = new Pane();
        pane.setPrefHeight(200);
        pane.setPrefWidth(200);
        pane.setMaxHeight(200);
        pane.setMaxWidth(200);

        Image image = new Image(getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("images/red square.png"));
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView( image );
        imageView.setImage(image);
        imageView.setFitHeight(200);
        imageView.setFitWidth(200);
        imageView.setPreserveRatio(true);
        imageView.setSmooth(false);
        pane.getChildren().add(imageView);

        Scene scene = new Scene( pane, 200, 200 );
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

With Image in loading

You can try loading the image with a predefined size.
By default, it will not preserve the `width:height` ratio: you can make it do so with

```
Image image = new Image("images/red square.png", 200, 200, true, false);
```

you can see information about that builder in [javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/image/Image.html#constructor.detail)

---

with [image view](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/index.html?javafx/scene/image/ImageView.html) use:

```
ImageView imageView = new ImageView("images/red square.png");
imageView.setPreserveRatio(true)
```

Comment: Both produce the same result. An image of a red square in a JavaFX Pane that for some reason is larger than 200x200.